# DIV Conditioning - Checking if an IMG exists within a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have the following lines of code in my website:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="the-post-thumbnail">
    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=Automatic+Thumbnail" alt="" width="" height="" /></p>
</div>

<div class="post-body">
    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/00FF00/FFFFFF?text=Manual+Thumbnail" alt="" width="" height="" /></p>      
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=Body+Image" alt="" width="" height="" /></p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
var ele = $('.post-body p:has(img):first');

if ($('.the-post-thumbnail img').length) {
  ele.hide();
}

else {
  ele.show();
}
```

What I am trying to do is:

1. Check if **there is** an image within the `the-post-thumbnail` div and if so, hide the manual thumbnail image within the `post-body`
2. Check if **there is not** an image within the `the-post-thumbnail` div and if so, show the manual thumbnail image within the `post-body`

This is partially working, however, what I've noticed is that if I remove the manual thumbnail image from within the `post-body` div, it will remove the second body image after the paragraph tag as well.

How can I target just the manual thumbnail image which is directly within the `post-body` div correctly so that I can achieve the two list items above, without adding additional classes?

**FYI:**

This is due to swapping my website's theme for a different one. The older version required me to place in a thumbnail image for each post manually at the top of the article, and the new theme does this for me automatically.  This resulted in duplicate images for older posts.

[**CodePen Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYVvZN?editors=101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/62/)**.

Just changing the position of `:first` selector should do the work, because it will select always the first `p` and check if it has an image :

```
var ele = $('.post-body p:first:has(img)');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any extra selectors, you could check for an image in the first paragraph.

```
var ele = $('.post-body p:eq(0):has(img)');
```